# What are the security features of JRE 8?

Tags: java

I was tasked with finding the security features of JRE 1.8 and compare it to JRE 1.7 update 51.  When I try to look for new security though, it only shows ">JDK< Security Enhancements" (ie. Not ">JRE< Security Enhancements") for 1.8.  Is that what I'm looking for?  If not, is it ever documented?

So, I'm just looking for the Java Runtime Environment, since I'm not developing any programs in Java.  So, are those JDK Security Enhancements the "security features of JRE 8" that I am looking for?

I ask here because "security features" felt so broad that I did not know what to start looking for.  I don't even know what to search in google.  I'm not that knowledgeable on Java at all.  Your help is appreciated.

Comment: This http://www.securitycurmudgeon.com/2014/03/20/spotlight-on-java-se-8-security/ contains a pretty good looking summary of Java7/8 security features..

Comment: Your comment is actually the answer, ahaha, too bad I can't check it :b

Answer (score 3):

JRE = Java Runtime Environment (meaning java.)
this will help you understand the differences between the different "versions", if you will, that java is listed/talked about.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250517/java-se-6-vs-jre-1-6-vs-jdk-1-6-what-do-these-mean

these should help you answer your questions:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8train-relnotes-latest-2153846.html

and

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jre-8-readme-2095710.html

Comment: So, yeah, I've been going through those as I await answers; but the security information surrounds "JDK", the development kit, and not the "JRE", the runtime environment.

Comment: Pretty much everything in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-8.html deals with the bits of the JDK that's also in the JRE.

Comment: So, you're saying the JDK Security Enhancement *IS* the documentation for the security features of JRE; great, I shall continue reading.